# Python Telebot ошибка при отправке аудио файла через json file_unique_id

Tags: python, json, telebot

Сам код:

```
elif message.text == 'Музыка ':
                bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, 'AgADMwsAAiEBIUs')
```

Использовал бота @ShowJsonBot для получения file_unique_id

Ошибка:

```
2021-03-31 16:54:50,814 (__init__.py:526 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. Wrong last symbol"
```

Comment: А может использовать метод `send_audio`?))

Comment: Через send_audio так же не получается отправить файл через file_unique_id. Это уже экспериментировал так сказать)

Такая же ошибка при send_audio:
2021-04-01 09:41:38,803 (__init__.py:526 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: can't unserialize it. Wrong last symbol"

Comment: так вы в метод передавайте `file_id`, а не `file_unique_id`. Чтобы посмотреть `file_id`   напишите 3 строки: `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])`
`def print_msg(message):`
    `print(message.audio.file_id)`

Comment: C file_id такая же ошибка, это file_id нужного аудио: CQACAgIAAxkBAAI8XWBkVDJEfCDBFTxPanGeThW5CIkRAAIzCwACIQEhS5K8dDRyPpRuHgQ

Comment: я надеюсь этот идентификатор вы получили в своем боте (тот код, который я привел в предыдущем комментарии), а не через @showjsonbot? Просто идентификаторы из одного бота нельзя использовать в другом боте.

Comment: Благодарю, получилось. Не знал что именно в бот нужно сначала отправить